# Griddle only showing columns in columnMeta array in setting after updating to version 0.7

Tags: reactjs, meteor-react, griddle

Just upgraded griddle and react packages to latest. Issue is griddle only showing columnMeta in setting after updating to version 0.7

I need to add all the columns in columnMeta array otherwise, they are not listed in the settings section

```
    let columnMeta = [
      {
        columnName: 'actions',
        order: 1,
        displayName: 'Actions',
        customComponent: this.getActions,
      },
      {
        columnName: 'imgUrls',
        customComponent: this.getImageComponent,
      },
      {
        columnName: 'name',
        customComponent: this.getNameComponent,
      },
      {
        columnName: 'block',
        customComponent: this.getMe,
      },
];
```

tested by adding this last column block.

package.json is

```
  "dependencies": {
    "draft-js": "^0.9.1",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^0.5.2",
    "draft-js-import-html": "^0.3.2",
    "externalify": "^0.1.0",
    "fbjs": "^0.8.8",
    "fibers": "^1.0.15",
    "formsy-react": "^0.19.0",
    "googleapis": "^16.1.0",
    "griddle-react": "^0.7.1",
    "imports": "^1.0.0",
    "keycode": "^2.1.8",
    "kisi-client": "^5.0.3",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.7.11",
    "material-ui": "v0.16.6",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",
    "multiparty": "^4.1.2",
    "radium": "^0.18.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "15.4.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-event-listener": "^0.4.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.1",
    "react-rte-gc": "0.11.6",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "react-widgets": "^3.4.5",
    "scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "simpl-schema": "0.0.3",
    "simple-assign": "^0.1.0",
    "twilio": "^2.11.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
}
```

Getting no error or issue in console, what could be the reason is any idea 
its Meteor + ReactJS project

Answer (score 0):

To get columns in griddle we need to use one more prop inside griddle

```
  <Griddle
    ref={(ref) => {this._griddle = ref}}
    useGriddleStyles={false}
    columnMetadata={columnMeta}
    results={this.getData()}
    columns={['id', 'name', 'age']} />
```

All the fields provided to columns prop will be displayed initally when we open page with griddle table

Hope this helps